# How to use multiple conditions in *ngIf directive with or` || operator Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have navbar which must change elements when user or admin logging in. After authentication I need that some elements were changed.For that I use ngIf directive.
This is my navbar template.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MEAN</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active" *ngIf="!auth.loggedIn() || !admin.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink = "/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!auth.loggedIn() || !admin.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink = "/login">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!auth.loggedIn() || !admin.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink = "/register" >Register</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink = "/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink = "/edit">Edit User</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="admin.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink = "/adminPage">Edit Users</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="admin.loggedIn()">
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have two services for handling users and admins pages.These services have functions which checks for token existence in local storage.
 This is functions from user service

```
loggedIn(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("authToken")){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

And this one from admin service

```
loggedIn(){
  if(localStorage.getItem("adminToken")){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

So I need that when user or admin logging in some of elements were hide (home,register,login)

```
<li class="nav-item active" *ngIf="!auth.loggedIn() || !admin.loggedIn()">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink = "/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!auth.loggedIn() || !admin.loggedIn()">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink = "/login">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!auth.loggedIn() || !admin.loggedIn()">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink = "/register" >Register</a>
          </li>
```

for that I've tried  to use or operator in ngIf directive but both of conditions not works.Sorry for language mistakes and Thanks for help

Comment: Are you injecting the two services into your component?

Comment: yeah i did it,but still it not works

Comment: It should, if you did everything right. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `li` elements are to be hidden when the user is logged in as user or admin, you should use:

```
*ngIf="!auth.loggedIn() && !admin.loggedIn()"
```

or

```
*ngIf="!(auth.loggedIn() || admin.loggedIn())"
```

---

With your current code

```
*ngIf="!auth.loggedIn() || !admin.loggedIn()"
```

the elements are hidden only if the user is logged in with both kinds of access at the same time, which is probably not possible.